# Visual Studio 2022 installation error: Couldn't install Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi

Tags: visual-studio

Yesterday I tried to update VS2022 to the latest version, but update failed with error `Couldn't install Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi.` After that update failed, I couldn't start VS anymore. I then tried to delete VS2022 and reinstall it, but same error occurs and I can't install it anymore. Here is error from log:

```
    Details
    MSI: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\VisualStudio\Packages\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.Msi,version=17.5.33306.270,productarch=x64\Microsoft.VisualStudio.MinShell.x64.Msi.msi, Properties:  REBOOT=ReallySuppress ARPSYSTEMCOMPONENT=1  MSIFASTINSTALL="7"  VSEXTUI="1"  VS7.71E8CD30_5AB3_4754_907A_EF452D9A12F5="C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional" 
    Return code: 1603
    Return code details: Fatal error during installation.
    Message Id: 1606
    Message Details: Could not access network location *:.
```

I tried clean boot, deleted temp folder, deleted visual studio installer. I can install VS2017 and run it, but I have projects in .NET CORE 7.0, and as I know, only vs2022 support that.

I tried to send reports to Microsoft, but first of all, I can login for report once in 20 tries, get some random error. And even after I login, I can't submit report, it's says:

```
Sorry, we couldn't send your report, because the server connection timed out. Please retry now or sign out from Visual Studio, sign in using Visual Studio and try again
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone get stuck like me:

Install this:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/fix-problems-that-block-programs-from-being-installed-or-removed-cca7d1b6-65a9-3d98-426b-e9f927e1eb4d

And then find any program that has in vs_minshellmsi or something similar in it's name and uninstall it. After that restart computer, and install Visual Studio.